# How to send and receive data from Android to communicate with BLE(cc2541)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

hi can anyone help me on this?

Comment: if you want code samples go here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am doing -

**ConnectedThread class for Input Stream, Output Stream, send and receive commands -**

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = new DataInputStream(tmpIn);
            mmOutStream = new DataOutputStream(tmpOut);


         }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) 
            {
                try 
                {  
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    if(mmInStream.available() > 0)
                    {
                           bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                           if(mHandler == null)
                                mHandler = new BBHandler(MyFragment.this);
                            else
                                mHandler.setTarget(MyFragment.this);

                           mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "BLE: Error reading from mmInStream");
                    setSetting("STATUS", "Disconnected");
                    break;
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "BLE: Null Pointer Exception mmInStream read or mHandler");
                }
            }
        }

        public void writeByte(char[] buffer)
        {
            for(int k=0; k < buffer.length; k++)
            {
                try 
                {
                    mmOutStream.writeByte(buffer[k]);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "BLE: IOException during writeByte", e);
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "BLE: NullPointerException during writeByte", e);
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "BlackBox: close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**And this is BBHandler class -**

```
static class BBHandler extends Handler{
        WeakReference<MyFragment> mFrag;

        BBHandler(MyFragment aFragment) {
            mFrag = new WeakReference<MyFragment>(aFragment);
        }

        public void setTarget(MyFragment aFragment) {
            mFrag.clear();
            mFrag = new WeakReference<MyFragment>(aFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            MyFragment theFrag = mFrag.get();
            if (theFrag != null) {
                theFrag.blackBoxData(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** `MyFragment` is your own fragment and `blackBoxData` is the method to call for execution steps. Your all logic should be here.

Comment: Thanx Ved, for your quick response but its not a classic bluetooth .its bluetooth low energy the are providing GATT api For it.

Comment: @user3852616 - You can use the above code for BLE as well. But if they provide you GATT specific preferences and settings then don't use it. And use only what they said as recommended.

Comment: Hi Ved..Gd mrng nice to talk to u.are u working on it(BLE android app).I want to send dtata to cc2541 from my app and i dont know about android much.please if u did it guide me bit .it wll very helpful if u share your source code with me...thanx in advance

Comment: Sure..I am working on that as well. Implemented code to receive commands from BLE to android and then to send commands from android to BLE. The short code is as you found in my answer. You can ping me any time for any problem.

Comment: Hi Ved.God Day to u.I am very new to the android.so its bit confusing to integrate all codes.please help me if u share your source code with me....

Comment: Hi dear.can u tell me abt the proximity and key exchange in android app fro cc2541..its really helps me a lot..

Comment: Hi Ved Prakash good evening.ya your suggestion is really valuable.and i am working on gatt profile based data transformation .here how to do it easily can you help me???data transfer is really a headache for me...

Comment: Hi VedPrakash,how are you doing??..its a big time to got your reply.please reply me i have some doubt.plz...

Answer (score 0):

I think using **BLE(Bluetooth law energy)** you can not able to send data from android device but you can only receave **BLE DATA** like **UUID,MajorId,MinorID** you have to send data from **iphone** or any other devices which is sending ble data continue. and if you want to receive ble data then try to download sour code from [here](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag) and Enjoy:-)